# Generating random numbers

Tags: probability, random

Suppose I would like to generate random numbers in a way that they satisfy some probability distribution with a mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, what is a formula for that?

Thank you.

Comment: Like a normal distribution?

Comment: once you can generate a uniform distribution you can just plug that into the function of whatever other distribution you want. Also note that 'probability distribution' could be a bunch of things (normal, uniform, exponential, etc). This isn't nearly specific enough.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Yes, but I am wondering if there is a formula in general, so for any distribution say $\rho$.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino: How do you plug that into another distribution? I suppose we can use the normal distribution as an example to begin with, I guess the "plugging in" will be similar for other distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following strategy is very general. Let $F(x)$ be the cumulative distribution of $X$. Assume $F$ is invertible and $U$ is a uniform random variable in $(0,1)$. Then $F^{-1}(U)$ is distributed as $X$. The proof is very simple:

$$P(F^{-1}(U) \leq x) = P(F(F^{-1}(U)) \leq F(x)) = P(U \leq F(x)) = F(x)$$

For example, if $X$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$,

$$F(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$$

$$x = -\frac{\log(1-F(x))}{\lambda}$$

Hence, $-\frac{\log(1-U)}{\lambda}$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to generate "true" uniform random numbers using a formula.  All formulas are deterministic.  Most cryptographically-secure methods of generating random numbers require the use of specialized hardware.  There are circuits to perform random number generation.  Once you have a uniform distribution of numbers you can then use something such as the Box-Muller transform to get normally distributed random numbers. Or maybe the Ziggurat algorithm is what you are looking for?

Perhaps use an algorithm that can generate random numbers with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ for any type of distribution.  The algorithm is not completely "random", and it is not a formula, but it is a process that can give fairly good random numbers.

For a ready-made solution, Matlab **normrnd** might be what you are looking for, if you want normally distributed random numbers.

If you want to generate sample numbers at random from any probability distribution, then the [inverse transform sampling method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling_method) might be the way to go.

In short, generate uniform random numbers, and then use other methods ([Random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918736/random-number-generator-that-produces-a-power-law-distribution)) to get the random numbers from the distribution that you want.